# How to properly implement mapStateToProps using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to do something really simple: Each time you click a button the value of 'current' in this component: https://github.com/conorhastings/react-thermometer increases.

The problem is that when I build, the console throws the following error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ( (29:11)

in this line:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
```

Here's the entire code of my container:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Thermometer from "react-thermometer";
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {incrementValue} from '../actions/index';

class Thermo extends Component{
  getValue(){
    return this.props.val;
  }

  render(){
    return(
          <div>
              <Thermometer
                      min={0}
                      max={90}
                      width={10}
                      height={90}
                      backgroundColor={'gray'}
                      fillColor={'pink'}
                      current={this.getValue()}
              />
              <Button onClick={() => this.props.incrementValue(val)}>+</Button>
          </div>
    )
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      val: state.val
    };
  }

  function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({incrementValue: incrementValue}, dispatch);
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Thermo);
```

And just in case, this is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the functions outside the class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Thermometer from "react-thermometer";
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {incrementValue} from '../actions/index';

class Thermo extends Component{
  getValue(){
    return this.props.val;
  }

  render(){
    return(
          <div>
              <Thermometer
                      min={0}
                      max={90}
                      width={10}
                      height={90}
                      backgroundColor={'gray'}
                      fillColor={'pink'}
                      current={this.getValue()}
              />
              <Button onClick={() => this.props.incrementValue(val)}>+</Button>
          </div>
    )
  }


}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      val: state.val
    };
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({incrementValue: incrementValue}, dispatch);
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Thermo);
```

You are passing the definition of your component to the function returned by `connect`, hence you don't make an instance of that class at any time. The `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are completely independent of your class, and are used before any instance of `Thermo` is made. Thus you need to have them outside.

Answer (score 3):

Move the function definitions outside the Component class

```
class Thermo extends Component {
    // ... component things
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      val: state.val
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({incrementValue: incrementValue}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Thermo);
```

---

Since you're using ES6, we have better sugary way of writing `connect`.

```
class Thermo extends Component {
    // ... component things
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({ val: state.val }),
    { incrementValue }
)(Thermo);
```

ie you actually don't need `mapStateToProps` and `matchDispatchToProps`.